# PDE $yu_{x}+xu_{y}=0, u(0,y)=e^{-y^2}$ - why the solution is determined only in the region ${x^2 ≤ y^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am solving the PDE
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
yu_{x}+xu_{y}=0\\ 
u(0,y)=e^{-y^2}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

My results are below. In the answer to this problem there is a statement saying that "a sketch of the characteristics shows that the solution is
determined only in the region ${x^2 ≤ y^2}$" which I don't quite follow.
Is my below solution not quite correct?

I got the following characteristic curves 
$$y^2=x^2+c$$
the general solution
$$u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)$$
and using the boundary condition the specific solution 
$$u(x,y)=e^{x^2-y^2}$$
which I pictured as below
[image]

**why the solution is determined only in the region ${x^2 ≤ y^2}$**?

**FURTHER UPDATES** 



I found some detailed explanation to the solution there:

https://www.math.upenn.edu/~vedranso/Math425_Homework1_Solutions.pdf

**My understanding is that only hyperbole which cross the y axis can be taken therefore the condition ${x^2 ≤ y^2}$ Is that correct?  However it is unclear to me how the C=1 was derived there. 

Can anybody help with the explanation?**




[image]

[image]

Comment: Your initial data is on $x=0$ and thus satisfies $y^2-x^2\ge 0$. Since $y^2-x^2$ is preserved on characteristics, the characteristics can only give you data on the points where $y^2-x^2\ge 0$.

Comment: I don't understand it, does it come from the initial condition ?

Comment: Characteristic curves are given by $y^{2} = \color{#f00}{-}x^{2} + c$.

Comment: @ Michal : There is a typo in the wording of your question. Either $yu_x-xu_y=0 \to u=f(x^2+y^2)$ , or $yu_x+xu_y=0 \to u=f(x^2-y^2)$

Comment: @ Michal : You wrote "I got the following characteristic curves (circles) $y^2=x^2+c$ ". If these were circles, the equation should be x^2+y^2=c.

Comment: @ JJacquelin  It should have been a plus there, I corrected the typo. You are right, those are not circles, (I corrected that either)

Comment: @Michal : You didn't corrected the main mistake : If there is no typo in $yu_x-xu_y=0$, the characteristic curves are NOT $y^2=x^2+c$ as you write it , but is $y^2+x^2=c$ . And the general solution is NOT $u=f(y^2-x^2)$ as you write it, but is $u=f(y^2+x^2)$.

Comment: @ JJacquelin: there was a typo,  $$yu_{x}+xu_{y}=0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$x dx= y dy$$
$$c+x^2=y^2$$
$$c=y^2-x^2$$
$$u(x,y)=f(y^2-x^2)$$
$$u(0,y)=f(y^2)=e^{-y^2}$$
$$w=y^2, \ \ y=\sqrt{w}, \ \ f(w)=e^{-y^2}=e^{-w}$$
$$u(x,y)=e^{(x^2-y^2)}$$